# React/Redux chaining a second API request and dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Still getting used to this.

I have checked out questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443786/react-redux-chain-a-next-dispatch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504123/react-redux-chain-or-promise-in-reducer) and I still feel uncomfortable about how to go about this. These are not clear from my perspective.

Basically I have clicked on the "Login" button and have requested a JWT login token and succesfully received it. What I have noticed is that I can at this point download those rarely changed lists like states or suburbs/postcodes which are large (the latter) and should be at the spa's immediate use rather than tacking it onto a call for a client.

I want to, upon successfully receiving the token immediately do an API call for those lists and store them in local storage. There is no "event" it should fire straight after a successful retreival of a JWT...

Here is the action for retreiving a JWT in react:

```
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username})

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data})
        saveJwt(data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        dispatch({type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message})
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }
```

I beleive the place for adding a second API call would be after "saveJwt()" but how.

Do/can I send it off to another export const action/function in another part of the application?

If I write something similar to this and by putting the name of the function in with a parameter of "JWT" eg

```
.then(retrieveSelectData)
```

that it will go off to that separate folder with that export function and execute  an API call at the same time applying a dispatch...and then return..

Could some one outline if this is a correct and reasonable way of making two API calls as one. I still have to get the JWT (and use it in the second) so I cant do the second call without the first.

Comment: Are you using `redux-thunk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your goal correctly, what you need here is a middleWare that will catch all `actions` that dispatched before the reducers catches them and can accept **functions** and holds a ref to the dispatcher.
Note that `reducers` can only accept [actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html#actions) that are plain objects and can't accept functions.

Enters `redux-thunk`, a middleware that does just that (and more) in only 11 lines of code.
It catches all actions (before the reducers) and checks to see if this `action === 'function'`.
If it is a `function` then it will call that `function` with dispatch as the argument.
If it's not a function it will leave it alone and let the `reducers` do their job.

Something like this:

```
function loadSomeThings() {
    return dispatch => {
        fetchFirstThingAsync.then(data => { // first API call
            dispatch({ type: 'FIRST_THING_SUCESS', data }); // you can dispatch this action if you want to let reducers take care of the first API call
            return fetchSecondThingAsync(data), // another API call with the data received from the first call that returns a promise
        })
        .then(data => {
             dispatch({ type: 'SECOND_THING_SUCESS', data }); // the reducers will handle this one as its the object they are waiting for
        });
    };
}
```